empty object returned with a bundled js library with webpack
Attempting to use graphology-layout-forceatlas2 on web.
Couldn't find a working build online.
Used webpack to create a bundle, however when included it returned an empty object even though there was 10kb of code.
package.json
  "name": "udm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.96.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}

webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js', 
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: 'ForceAtlas2',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
    },
    mode: 'production'
};

src/index.js
const forceAtlas2 = require('graphology-layout-forceatlas2');
window.ForceAtlas2 = forceAtlas2;

bundle.js
!function(t,e){"object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module?module.exports=e():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define([],e):"object"==typeof exports?exports.ForceAtlas2=e():t.ForceAtlas2=e()}(self,(()=>(()=>{var t={435:t=>{t.exports={linLogMode:!1,outboundAttractionDistribution:!1,adjustSizes:!1,edgeWeightInfluence:1,scalingRatio:1,strongGravityMode:!1,gravity:1,slowDown:1,barnesHutOptimize:!1,barnesHutTheta:.5}},924:(t,e)=>{e.assign=function(t){t=t||{};var e,o,n,r=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(1);for(e=0,n=r.length;e<n;e++)if(r[e])for(o in r[e])t[o]=r[e][o];return t},e.validateSettings=function(t){return"linLogMode"in t&&"boolean"!=typeof t.linLogMode?{message:"the `linLogMode` setting should be a boolean."}:"outboundAttractionDistribution"in t&&"boolean"!=typeof t.outboundAttractionDistribution?{message:"the `outboundAttractionDistribution` setting should be a boolean."}:"adjustSizes"in t&&"boolean"!=typeof t.adjustSizes?{message:"the `adjustSizes` setting should be a boolean."}:"edgeWeightInfluence"in t&&"number"!=typeof t.edgeWeightInfluence?{message:"the `edgeWeightInfluence` setting should be a number."}:!("scalingRatio"in t)||"number"==typeof t.scalingRatio&&t.scalingRatio>=0?"strongGravityMode"in t&&"boolean"!=typeof t.strongGravityMode?{message:"the `strongGravityMode` setting should be a boolean."}:!("gravity"in t)||"number"==typeof t.gravity&&t.gravity>=0?"slowDown"in t&&!("number"==typeof t.slowDown||t.slowDown>=0)?{message:"the `slowDown` setting should be a number >= 0."}:"barnesHutOptimize"in t&&"boolean"!=typeof t.barnesHutOptimize?{message:"the `barnesHutOptimize` setting should be a boolean."}:!("barnesHutTheta"in t)||"number"==typeof t.barnesHutTheta&&t.barnesHutTheta>=0?null:{message:"the `barnesHutTheta` setting should be a number >= 0."}:{message:"the `gravity` setting should be a number >= 0."}:{message:"the `scalingRatio` setting should be a number >= 0."}},e.graphToByteArrays=function(t,e){var o,n=t.order,r=t.size,i={},a=new Float32Array(10*n),s=new Float32Array(3*r);return o=0,t.forEachNode((function(t,e){i[t]=o,a[o]=e.x,a[o+1]=e.y,a[o+2]=0,a[o+3]=0,a[o+4]=0,a[o+5]=0,a[o+6]=1,a[o+7]=1,a[o+8]=e.size||1,a[o+9]=e.fixed?1:0,o+=10})),o=0,t.forEachEdge((function(t,n,r,u,f,g,l){var h=i[r],c=i[u],d=e(t,n,r,u,f,g,l);a[h+6]+=d,a[c+6]+=d,s[o]=h,s[o+1]=c,s[o+2]=d,o+=3})),{nodes:a,edges:s}},e.assignLayoutChanges=function(t,e,o){var n=0;t.updateEachNodeAttributes((function(t,r){return r.x=e[n],r.y=e[n+1],n+=10,o?o(t,r):r}))},e.readGraphPositions=function(t,e){var o=0;t.forEachNode((function(t,n){e[o]=n.x,e[o+1]=n.y,o+=10}))},e.collectLayoutChanges=function(t,e,o){for(var n=t.nodes(),r={},i=0,a=0,s=e.length;i<s;i+=10){if(o){var u=Object.assign({},t.getNodeAttributes(n[a]));u.x=e[i],u.y=e[i+1],u=o(n[a],u),r[n[a]]={x:u.x,y:u.y}}else r[n[a]]={x:e[i],y:e[i+1]};a++}return r},e.createWorker=function(t){var e=window.URL||window.webkitURL,o=t.toString(),n=e.createObjectURL(new Blob(["("+o+").call(this);"],{type:"text/javascript"})),r=new Worker(n);return e.revokeObjectURL(n),r}},697:(t,e,o)=>{var n=o(154),r=o(183).Fd,i=o(675),a=o(924),s=o(435);function u(t,e,o){if(!n(e))throw new Error("graphology-layout-forceatlas2: the given graph is not a valid graphology instance.");"number"==typeof o&&(o={iterations:o});var u=o.iterations;if("number"!=typeof u)throw new Error("graphology-layout-forceatlas2: invalid number of iterations.");if(u<=0)throw new Error("graphology-layout-forceatlas2: you should provide a positive number of iterations.");var f=r("getEdgeWeight"in o?o.getEdgeWeight:"weight").fromEntry,g="function"==typeof o.outputReducer?o.outputReducer:null,l=a.assign({},s,o.settings),h=a.validateSettings(l);if(h)throw new Error("graphology-layout-forceatlas2: "+h.message);var c,d=a.graphToByteArrays(e,f);for(c=0;c<u;c++)i(l,d.nodes,d.edges);if(!t)return a.collectLayoutChanges(e,d.nodes);a.assignLayoutChanges(e,d.nodes,g)}var f=u.bind(null,!1);f.assign=u.bind(null,!0),f.inferSettings=function(t){var e="number"==typeof t?t:t.order;return{barnesHutOptimize:e>2e3,strongGravityMode:!0,gravity:.05,scalingRatio:10,slowDown:1+Math.log(e)}},t.exports=f},675:t=>{var e=10;t.exports=function(t,o,n){var r,i,a,s,u,f,g,l,h,c,d,b,y,p,m,M,w,v,A,E,x,D,q,L=o.length,R=n.length,z=t.adjustSizes,H=t.barnesHutTheta*t.barnesHutTheta,j=[];for(a=0;a<L;a+=e)o[a+4]=o[a+2],o[a+5]=o[a+3],o[a+2]=0,o[a+3]=0;if(t.outboundAttractionDistribution){for(d=0,a=0;a<L;a+=e)d+=o[a+6];d/=L/e}if(t.barnesHutOptimize){var S,G,T,O=1/0,W=-1/0,k=1/0,F=-1/0;for(a=0;a<L;a+=e)O=Math.min(O,o[a+0]),W=Math.max(W,o[a+0]),k=Math.min(k,o[a+1]),F=Math.max(F,o[a+1]);var N=W-O,U=F-k;for(N>U?F=(k-=(N-U)/2)+N:W=(O-=(U-N)/2)+U,j[0]=-1,j[1]=(O+W)/2,j[2]=(k+F)/2,j[3]=Math.max(W-O,F-k),j[4]=-1,j[5]=-1,j[6]=0,j[7]=0,j[8]=0,r=1,a=0;a<L;a+=e)for(i=0,T=3;;){if(!(j[i+5]>=0)){if(j[i+0]<0){j[i+0]=a;break}if(j[i+5]=9*r,l=j[i+3]/2,j[(h=j[i+5])+0]=-1,j[h+1]=j[i+1]-l,j[h+2]=j[i+2]-l,j[h+3]=l,j[h+4]=h+9,j[h+5]=-1,j[h+6]=0,j[h+7]=0,j[h+8]=0,j[(h+=9)+0]=-1,j[h+1]=j[i+1]-l,j[h+2]=j[i+2]+l,j[h+3]=l,j[h+4]=h+9,j[h+5]=-1,j[h+6]=0,j[h+7]=0,j[h+8]=0,j[(h+=9)+0]=-1,j[h+1]=j[i+1]+l,j[h+2]=j[i+2]-l,j[h+3]=l,j[h+4]=h+9,j[h+5]=-1,j[h+6]=0,j[h+7]=0,j[h+8]=0,j[(h+=9)+0]=-1,j[h+1]=j[i+1]+l,j[h+2]=j[i+2]+l,j[h+3]=l,j[h+4]=j[i+4],j[h+5]=-1,j[h+6]=0,j[h+7]=0,j[h+8]=0,r+=4,S=o[j[i+0]+0]<j[i+1]?o[j[i+0]+1]<j[i+2]?j[i+5]:j[i+5]+9:o[j[i+0]+1]<j[i+2]?j[i+5]+18:j[i+5]+27,j[i+6]=o[j[i+0]+6],j[i+7]=o[j[i+0]+0],j[i+8]=o[j[i+0]+1],j[S+0]=j[i+0],j[i+0]=-1,S===(G=o[a+0]<j[i+1]?o[a+1]<j[i+2]?j[i+5]:j[i+5]+9:o[a+1]<j[i+2]?j[i+5]+18:j[i+5]+27)){if(T--){i=S;continue}T=3;break}j[G+0]=a;break}S=o[a+0]<j[i+1]?o[a+1]<j[i+2]?j[i+5]:j[i+5]+9:o[a+1]<j[i+2]?j[i+5]+18:j[i+5]+27,j[i+7]=(j[i+7]*j[i+6]+o[a+0]*o[a+6])/(j[i+6]+o[a+6]),j[i+8]=(j[i+8]*j[i+6]+o[a+1]*o[a+6])/(j[i+6]+o[a+6]),j[i+6]+=o[a+6],i=S}}if(t.barnesHutOptimize){for(b=t.scalingRatio,a=0;a<L;a+=e)for(i=0;;)if(j[i+5]>=0){if(M=Math.pow(o[a+0]-j[i+7],2)+Math.pow(o[a+1]-j[i+8],2),4*(c=j[i+3])*c/M<H){if(y=o[a+0]-j[i+7],p=o[a+1]-j[i+8],!0===z?M>0?(w=b*o[a+6]*j[i+6]/M,o[a+2]+=y*w,o[a+3]+=p*w):M<0&&(w=-b*o[a+6]*j[i+6]/Math.sqrt(M),o[a+2]+=y*w,o[a+3]+=p*w):M>0&&(w=b*o[a+6]*j[i+6]/M,o[a+2]+=y*w,o[a+3]+=p*w),(i=j[i+4])<0)break;continue}i=j[i+5]}else if((f=j[i+0])>=0&&f!==a&&(M=(y=o[a+0]-o[f+0])*y+(p=o[a+1]-o[f+1])*p,!0===z?M>0?(w=b*o[a+6]*o[f+6]/M,o[a+2]+=y*w,o[a+3]+=p*w):M<0&&(w=-b*o[a+6]*o[f+6]/Math.sqrt(M),o[a+2]+=y*w,o[a+3]+=p*w):M>0&&(w=b*o[a+6]*o[f+6]/M,o[a+2]+=y*w,o[a+3]+=p*w)),(i=j[i+4])<0)break}else for(b=t.scalingRatio,s=0;s<L;s+=e)for(u=0;u<s;u+=e)y=o[s+0]-o[u+0],p=o[s+1]-o[u+1],!0===z?(M=Math.sqrt(y*y+p*p)-o[s+8]-o[u+8])>0?(w=b*o[s+6]*o[u+6]/M/M,o[s+2]+=y*w,o[s+3]+=p*w,o[u+2]-=y*w,o[u+3]-=p*w):M<0&&(w=100*b*o[s+6]*o[u+6],o[s+2]+=y*w,o[s+3]+=p*w,o[u+2]-=y*w,o[u+3]-=p*w):(M=Math.sqrt(y*y+p*p))>0&&(w=b*o[s+6]*o[u+6]/M/M,o[s+2]+=y*w,o[s+3]+=p*w,o[u+2]-=y*w,o[u+3]-=p*w);for(h=t.gravity/t.scalingRatio,b=t.scalingRatio,a=0;a<L;a+=e)w=0,y=o[a+0],p=o[a+1],M=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y,2)+Math.pow(p,2)),t.strongGravityMode?M>0&&(w=b*o[a+6]*h):M>0&&(w=b*o[a+6]*h/M),o[a+2]-=y*w,o[a+3]-=p*w;for(b=1*(t.outboundAttractionDistribution?d:1),g=0;g<R;g+=3)s=n[g+0],u=n[g+1],l=n[g+2],m=Math.pow(l,t.edgeWeightInfluence),y=o[s+0]-o[u+0],p=o[s+1]-o[u+1],!0===z?(M=Math.sqrt(y*y+p*p)-o[s+8]-o[u+8],t.linLogMode?t.outboundAttractionDistribution?M>0&&(w=-b*m*Math.log(1+M)/M/o[s+6]):M>0&&(w=-b*m*Math.log(1+M)/M):t.outboundAttractionDistribution?M>0&&(w=-b*m/o[s+6]):M>0&&(w=-b*m)):(M=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y,2)+Math.pow(p,2)),t.linLogMode?t.outboundAttractionDistribution?M>0&&(w=-b*m*Math.log(1+M)/M/o[s+6]):M>0&&(w=-b*m*Math.log(1+M)/M):t.outboundAttractionDistribution?(M=1,w=-b*m/o[s+6]):(M=1,w=-b*m)),M>0&&(o[s+2]+=y*w,o[s+3]+=p*w,o[u+2]-=y*w,o[u+3]-=p*w);if(!0===z)for(a=0;a<L;a+=e)1!==o[a+9]&&((v=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(o[a+2],2)+Math.pow(o[a+3],2)))>10&&(o[a+2]=10*o[a+2]/v,o[a+3]=10*o[a+3]/v),A=o[a+6]*Math.sqrt((o[a+4]-o[a+2])*(o[a+4]-o[a+2])+(o[a+5]-o[a+3])*(o[a+5]-o[a+3])),E=Math.sqrt((o[a+4]+o[a+2])*(o[a+4]+o[a+2])+(o[a+5]+o[a+3])*(o[a+5]+o[a+3]))/2,x=.1*Math.log(1+E)/(1+Math.sqrt(A)),D=o[a+0]+o[a+2]*(x/t.slowDown),o[a+0]=D,q=o[a+1]+o[a+3]*(x/t.slowDown),o[a+1]=q);else for(a=0;a<L;a+=e)1!==o[a+9]&&(A=o[a+6]*Math.sqrt((o[a+4]-o[a+2])*(o[a+4]-o[a+2])+(o[a+5]-o[a+3])*(o[a+5]-o[a+3])),E=Math.sqrt((o[a+4]+o[a+2])*(o[a+4]+o[a+2])+(o[a+5]+o[a+3])*(o[a+5]+o[a+3]))/2,x=o[a+7]*Math.log(1+E)/(1+Math.sqrt(A)),o[a+7]=Math.min(1,Math.sqrt(x*(Math.pow(o[a+2],2)+Math.pow(o[a+3],2))/(1+Math.sqrt(A)))),D=o[a+0]+o[a+2]*(x/t.slowDown),o[a+0]=D,q=o[a+1]+o[a+3]*(x/t.slowDown),o[a+1]=q);return{}}},183:(t,e)=>{function o(t){return"number"!=typeof t||isNaN(t)?1:t}e.Fd=function(t){return function(t,e){var o={},n=function(t){return void 0===t?e:t};"function"==typeof e&&(n=e);var r=function(e){return n(e[t])},i=function(){return n(void 0)};return"string"==typeof t?(o.fromAttributes=r,o.fromGraph=function(t,e){return r(t.getEdgeAttributes(e))},o.fromEntry=function(t,e){return r(e)},o.fromPartialEntry=o.fromEntry,o.fromMinimalEntry=o.fromEntry):"function"==typeof t?(o.fromAttributes=function(){throw new Error("graphology-utils/getters/createEdgeValueGetter: irrelevant usage.")},o.fromGraph=function(e,o){var r=e.extremities(o);return n(t(o,e.getEdgeAttributes(o),r[0],r[1],e.getNodeAttributes(r[0]),e.getNodeAttributes(r[1]),e.isUndirected(o)))},o.fromEntry=function(e,o,r,i,a,s,u){return n(t(e,o,r,i,a,s,u))},o.fromPartialEntry=function(e,o,r,i){return n(t(e,o,r,i))},o.fromMinimalEntry=function(e,o){return n(t(e,o))}):(o.fromAttributes=i,o.fromGraph=i,o.fromEntry=i,o.fromMinimalEntry=i),o}(t,o)}},154:t=>{t.exports=function(t){return null!==t&&"object"==typeof t&&"function"==typeof t.addUndirectedEdgeWithKey&&"function"==typeof t.dropNode&&"boolean"==typeof t.multi}}},e={};const o=function o(n){var r=e[n];if(void 0!==r)return r.exports;var i=e[n]={exports:{}};return t[n](i,i.exports,o),i.exports}(697);return window.ForceAtlas2={assign:o.assign,inferSettings:o.inferSettings,DEFAULTS:o.DEFAULTS},{}})()));```

